# JS Minification / Closure Compiler changes numbers from base 10 to something else?

Tags: javascript, minify

I'm running some JS through googles closure compiler and noticed something about how it handles numbers. It seems that they are converted into something other than base 10 and I can't figure out what it is.

```
javascript:(function(){
 var x = 30000;
 console.log(x);
})();
```

Results in:

```
(function(){console.log(3E4)})();
```

How is 3E4 == 30000?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's callled [Scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation), especially the "E notation" part is what you're after.

Basically, `aEb === a * Math.pow(10, b)` (though this would be a syntax error - `a` and `b` have to be literals, `b` even has to be an integer).

```
3 * Math.pow(10, 4) === 30000; // true
```

The `3` and `4` are just in base 10. This has little to do with bases in fact.

Comment: Makes sense - Do you have a JS reference for this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Number lists all of the accepted numeric formats.

Answer (score 1):

The 3e4 is the same as "saying" 3 multiplied by 4 orders of magnitude, or a 3 with 4 zeros.